# Examples of the difference between `prompt/control` and `shift/reset`

Tags: scheme, ml, delimited-continuations

I am not sure I understand the difference between the delimited continuation operator pairs `prompt/control` and `reset/shift`. I understand some basic examples of use, but in those examples their behavior is the same.

I have found this example in "[On the Dynamic Extent of Delimited Continuations](https://www.brics.dk/RS/05/2/BRICS-RS-05-2.pdf)", by Dariusz Biernacki and Olivier Danvy:

```
reset
  (fn () => shift (fn k => 10 + (k 100))
          + shift (fn k’ => 1))

prompt 
  (fn () => control (fn k => 10 + (k 100))
          + control (fn k’ => 1))
```

which I have translated into Scheme and ran successfully with the expected results in Racket using the `racket/control` library:

```
(reset  (+ (shift   k  (+ 10 (k 100)))
           (shift   kk 1))) 
   ;; ==> 11

(prompt (+ (control k  (+ 10 (k 100)))
           (control kk 1))) 
   ;; ==> 1
```

Their explanation is that,

> In the first case, when `k` is applied, the expression `shift (fn kk => 1)` is evaluated in  a  context  that  could  be  represented  functionally  as `fn v => 100 + v` and  in a meta-context that could
> be represented as `(fn v => 10 + v) ::  nil`; this context is captured
> and discarded and the intermediate answer is `1`; this intermediate
> answer is plugged into the top context from the meta-context, i.e.,
> `fn v => 10 + v` is applied to `1`; the next intermediate answer is
> `11`; and it is the final answer since the meta-context is empty.
>
> In  the  second  case,  when `k` is  applied,  the  expression control
> `(fn kk => 1)` is evaluated in a context that results from composing
> `fn v => 10 + v` and `fn v => 100 + v` (and  therefore  could  be
> represented  functionally  as `fn v => 10 + (100 + v)`), and in a
> meta-context which is empty; this context is captured and discarded
> and the  intermediate  answer is `1`;  and  it  is  the  final  answer
> since  the  meta-context  is empty.

I was confused by the "meta-context" idea, which they define as

> Intuitively, an evaluation context  represents the  rest  of the  computation  up  to the
> nearest enclosing delimiter, and a meta-context represents all of the remaining computation.

I didn't get the idea of "all of the remaining computation" here, I'm not sure
why it would be `(fn v => 10 + v) ::  nil` in the first example (why exactly that piece of code?)

I was wondering if there is any more examples, possible with more details, of the
differences between those two pairs of operators, possibly without too much use of formal semantics,
which is a really above my head.

**edit:** I also see that the order of the two `shift`-surrounded expressions does make a difference: if I swap them, then the result is `1` for both `control` and `reset`.

Answer (score 11):

First, let's recall the reduction rules of both `prompt/control` and `reset/shift`.

```lisp
(prompt val) => val
(prompt E[control k expr]) => (prompt ((λk. expr) (λv. E[v])))
; E is free from prompt
```

```lisp
(reset val) => val
(reset E[shift k expr]) => (reset ((λk. expr) (λv. (reset E[v]))))
; E is free from reset
```

We can see that `reset` and `prompt` are the same. However, the second rule is subtly different. The `reset/shift` pair introduces a reset around `E[v]` which limits the scope of what can be captured by the `shift` inside `E[v]`

Let's now reduce both expressions step by step.

First, `shift/reduce`:

```lisp
(reset (+ (shift k (+ 10 (k 100))) (shift kk 1)))
=> (reset ((λk. (+ 10 (k 100))) (λv. (reset (+ v (shift kk 1))))))
; Here, E[v] = (+ v (shift kk 1))
=> (reset ((λk. (+ 10 (k 100))) (λv. (reset ((λkk. 1) (λw. (+ v w)))))))
; Here, E'[w] = (+ v w)
; Because of the reset, `E'[w]` catches only `(+ v w)`
; which gets discarded right away.
=> (reset ((λk. (+ 10 (k 100))) (λv. (reset 1))))
=> (reset ((λk. (+ 10 (k 100))) (λv. 1)))
=> (reset (+ 10 ((λv. 1) 100)))
=> (reset (+ 10 1))
=> (reset 11)
=> 11
```

Secondly, `prompt/control`:

```lisp
(prompt  (+ (control k (+ 10 (k 100))) (control kk 1)))
=> (prompt ((λk. (+ 10 (k 100))) (λv. (+ v (control kk 1)))))
; Here, E[v] = (+ v (control kk 1))
=> (prompt ((λkk. 1) (λw. ((λk. (+ 10 (k 100))) (λv. (+ v w))))))
; Here, E'[w] = ((λk. (+ 10 (k 100))) (λv. (+ v w)))
; Because there is no `prompt` the scope of `E'[w]` is much larger and
; everything in it get discarded right away
=> (prompt 1)
=> 1
```

In conclusion, there is a difference only if there are at least 2 `control`/`shift` operators and `shift` reduces the scope of what can be captured by the context `E'`.